# Dual Monitors - Running Win 8 at Home and Remote to Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I am running windows 8 at home on my laptop and remoting into a machine in a closet that runs windows 7.  the machine that i am remoting to is set up to run on one monitor.  i would like to use a **dual monitor** set up at home.  i am told this is possible but have yet to find a solution that works.  I would like to use both of my monitors at home for the remote connection.

can anyone help?

I have tried updating the .rdp file and running multimon and clicking the use all my monitors in the remote connection display tab.

is there something i am missing?

Comment: Do you want the the remote desktop session to extend over two monitors? Or have two monitors one with Win8 and the other with the RDP into Win7?

Comment: Is the remote computer Windows 7 *Pro* or Windows 7 *Ultimate* (or Enterprise)? Only Ultimate/Enterprise support multi-monitor RDP.

Comment: it is windows 7 professional.

Comment: Then you will need to either upgrade it to Ultimate, or use a different technology, such as VNC. Note that the latter will require you to Hook multiple monitors up to the remote computer, even if they are not used, because VNC cannot resize the desktop to the local machine's screen size like RDP can.

Answer (score 5):

If you have **Windows 7 Ultimate** or **Windows 7 Enterprise** as the host/remote computer, tell RDC to use all your screens when connecting:

[image]

[All other versions of Windows 7 do not support multi-monitor RDP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: I have tried clicking the use all my monitors.  I would like to use both of my monitors at home for the remote connection.

Comment: Sadly this seems to have been a pain point for many years based on some threads on Microsoft's TechNET forums. It's upgrade or use something other than RDP.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  since it's a work PC getting an upgrade is a lost cause.  i will have to deal :)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answerer stated, when connecting to a remote *Windows 7* PC from a *Windows 7* client, the remote PC must have *Windows 7 Ultimate* or *Windows 7 Enterprise* if you want to use the `/multimon` feature (the client doesn't have to be *Ultimate*, only the remote PC). Since your remote PC is *Windows 7 Professional*, you will have to stick with `/span`. If you don't know what that is, see [the instructions here](http://computing.caes.ucdavis.edu/guides/span-multiple-monitors-with-remote-desktop).

Also, you mentioned that the client PC has *Windows 8*-- I read somewhere else that the version of Remote Desktop included in *Windows 8* does not include the multiple-monitor feature, only *Windows 8 Pro* and *Windows 8 Enterprise*, and that unlike *Windows 7*, both the client ***and*** the server had to have the correct license. I can't find where I read that, but I thought it best to mention it as an FYI.